# using jquery :nth-child() selector with a parameter

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use the jquery selector :nth-child() with a parameter ?

```
var ok = function(a)
{ 
    $("#divid:nth-child(a)").click(function()
    {
           .............
    });
};

$(function()
{
    $("#divId2").click(ok(4));
});
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You should take more time when typing up your question.

Comment: Are you sure you want to define a click event inside a click event?

Comment: Why are doing `$("#divid:nth-child...`? Do you have more than one element with the same ID on the page? And this `$("#divId2").click(ok(4));` doesn't make sense unless the `ok` function returns a handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, simply do `$('#divid:nth-child(' + a + ')').blabla`.

Oh, and make sure a is actually a number, or you might get unexpected results/errors.